# can I multiply the equation and code it in such a manner as shown

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coordinate-systems, rotations

For the following formula solving for world coordinates [X Y Z]:

$eq.(1)\begin{bmatrix}
  X \\
  Y \\
  Z \\
\end{bmatrix} = R^{T}\begin{bmatrix}
  u\\
  v \\
  1 \\
\end{bmatrix} -R^{T}t  
$

Where R' is R$^{T}$, Wworld is  $\begin{bmatrix}
  X\\
  Y \\
  Z \\
\end{bmatrix}$ Wcam is $\begin{bmatrix}
  u\\
  v \\
  1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ and tvec is a 3 x 1 mat called t, is it okay to code the minus as shown below?

$Wworld = R' Wcam -(R't) $

> `Wworld = R.transpose()* Wcam - (R.transpose() * tvec)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this Python? If so, then you'll need to call the transpose function as `np.transpose(R)` rather than the way you have it written. To save operations, you may also want to factor out the $R^T$ and compute it as follows:

> `Wworld = np.transpose(R) * (Wcam - tvec)`.

I am assuming this whole time you have the line `import numpy as np` earlier in your code. Other than the way you're calling the transpose function, your way is correct too.

Comment: Is C/C++, opencv.

Comment: Wworld = R.t() * (Wcam - tvec)

Comment: Yup! That should work. Best of luck!